# Codejock / CXTPReportControl: find row by record

Tags: c++, mfc

Is there a way to find associated CXTPReportRow object for given CXTPReportRecord object?

I can get the the record object by calling

```
CXTPReportRecord* pRecord = pRow->GetRecord();
```

but how to find the row by record?

P.S. I have asked for a support codejock team but didn't receive a response yet.

Thanks,
Khachatur

Comment: Have you tried the CodeJock forums?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, finally I got a solution.

You can call FindInTree for a Rows collection

```
CXTPReportRows* pRows = my_grid.GetRows();
CXTPReportRow* pRow = pRows->FindInTree(pRecord);
```